# How can I write a strings to file with linebreaks inbetween?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to be able to write some values to a file whilst creating blank lines in between. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
TextWriter w_Test = new StreamWriter(file_test);
foreach (string results in searchResults)
{
    w_Test.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(results));
    var list1 = File.ReadAllLines(results).Skip(10);
    foreach (string listResult in list1)
    {
        w_Test.WriteLine(listResult);
    }
}
w_Test.Close();
```

This creates `'Test'` with the following output:

```
result1
listResult1
listResult2
result2
listResult3
result3
result4
```

I want to write the results so that each result block is 21 lines in size before writing the next, e.g.

```
result1
(20 lines even if no 'listResult' found)
result2
(20 lines even if no 'listResult' found)
etc.......
```

What would be the best way of doing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextWriter w_Test = new StreamWriter(file_test);
foreach (string results in searchResults)
{
    int noLinesOutput = 0;
    w_Test.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(results));
    noLinesOutput++;
    var list1 = File.ReadAllLines(results).Skip(10);
    foreach (string listResult in list1)
    {
        w_Test.WriteLine(listResult);
        noLinesOutput++;
    }
    for ( int i = 20; i > noLinesOutput; i-- )
        w_Test.WriteLine();
}
w_Test.Close();
```

Comment: Used this answer as it is only used once and sits nicely in current code.

Comment: Use `File.ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` if the file is large since the former doesn't need to read the whole file. Also, this solution outputs all lines of the file even if there are more than 20 lines. Is this correct?

Comment: The solution pulls data from a file created by myself manually so if the results would ever go beyond 20 then I can increase the value in this section. I will change it to `File.ReadLines` though, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple helper method I use in such cases:

```
// pad the sequence with 'elem' until it's 'count' elements long
static IEnumerable<T> PadRight<T>(IEnumerable<T> enm,
    T elem,
    int count)
{
    int ii = 0;
    foreach(var elem in enm)
    {
        yield return elem;
        ii += 1;
    }
    for (; ii < count; ++ii)
    {
        yield return elem;
    }
}
```

Then

```
foreach (string listResult in 
    PadRight(list1, "", 20))
{
    w_Test.WriteLine(listResult);
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with this loop:

```
var lines = 20;
foreach(string fullPath in searchResults)
{
    List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
    allLines.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath));
    int currentLine = 0;
    foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(fullPath).Skip(10))
    {
        if(++currentLine > lines) break;
        allLines.Add(line);
    }
    while (currentLine++ < lines)
        allLines.Add(String.Empty);
    File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, allLines);
}
```